# How generate a Fat Maven Plugin with maven-plugin-plugin?

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, maven-plugin

In our company, we've created a Maven plugin using maven-plugin-plugin v3.5, that normally contains 20kb.

The issue begun two days ago, because repo.jenkins-ci.org proxy is not working properly. So, our clients builds were affected because it wasn't possible to download the dependencies of our plugins, failing builds due:

`Failed to collect dependencies at our-project:jar:1.6.2 -> our-project:jar:1.6.2 -> com.devfactory.utqg:utqg-github:jar:1.6.2 -> org.kohsuke:github-api:jar:1.77 -> com.infradna.tool:bridge-method-annotation:jar:1.14 -> org.jenkins-ci:annotation-indexer:jar:1.4: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.jenkins-ci:annotation-indexer:jar:1.4: Could not transfer artifact org.jenkins-ci:jenkins:pom:1.26 from/to repo.jenkins-ci.org (http://repo.jenkins-ci.org/public/): Failed to transfer file: http://repo.jenkins-ci.org/public/org/jenkins-ci/jenkins/1.26/jenkins-1.26.pom. Return code is: 502 , ReasonPhrase:Bad Gateway. -> [Help 1]`

So, our approach to that problem was focused in creating a Fat Maven Plugin (**not a Fat Jar!**). But, using Maven Shade plugin is not suitable for copying the artifacts, because plugin execution fails due the jar signature.

Does anybody have generated a **fat Maven plugin**? If yes, how?

Comment: you need to create a jar jar file? Right. If so use either maven-assembly-plugin or maven-shade-plugin. Furthermore using repo.jenkins-ci.org is the wrong location to download maven plugins. Maven Plugins are located in Maven Central which is configured in Maven itself by default. Best is to start using a repository manager....

Comment: no @khmarbaise, I need to create a FAT maven plugin, which is, by definition, a Jar file. I'm using maven-plugin-plugin for that.

Comment: What is the purpose of this plugin? So you rewrite maven-shade-plugin/maven-assembly-plugin.

Comment: @khmarbaise its a company plugin, that does some code analysis. Instead of having a 20kb maven plugin, I would like to have a full jar, with all dependencies on it.

Answer (score 1):

> The issue begun two days ago, because repo.jenkins-ci.org proxy is not
>   working properly. So, our clients builds were affected because it wasn't possible to download the dependencies of our plugins,

I recommend to run your own Maven Repository Manager to avoid these kind of issues: https://maven.apache.org/repository-management.html

Configure the single group in your settings.xml (mirror): http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/2.8/reference/maven-sect-single-group.html

Don't manage repositories in your POMs, but only as proxies in your Maven Repository Manager.

Comment: We currently have an internal Nexus, but we can't guarantee that our repos will be operational 100% of the time on all requests. Also, this dependency that is giving this problem is not ours, but an 4th level inner dependency on tree. (our jar -> first 3party jar -> second 3party jar -> jar giving problem)

So, instead of having a 20kb maven plugin (that is currently our size), we would like to have an 15mb maven plugin, with all files inside of it.

Any idea about it?

Comment: It's not the recommended way and I think you would still have similar issues if you repo is not available. You really should get a stable Maven Repository Manager I think. What product do you use? What issues do you have? Maybe good for a follow-up qestion.

Comment: You can define any number of proxy repos for third party libraries. There should be no issue regarding this.